# how can i fix this syntax error in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

```
SELECT account_name ,sum(total_balance) from transaction 
where account_name IN('cash','a/r','supplies','prepaid','land','gold')
AS total_assets
ORDER BY account_name
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as total_assets order by account_name LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3

Comment: I guess you need to need give a name to  `sum(total_balance) AS total_assets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an alias in the wrong place.

```
SELECT account_name ,sum(total_balance) from transaction 
where account_name IN('cash','a/r','supplies','prepaid','land','gold')
AS total_assets
ORDER BY account_name
```

should be

```
SELECT account_name ,sum(total_balance) AS total_assets
from transaction 
where account_name IN('cash','a/r','supplies','prepaid','land','gold')
ORDER BY account_name
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `AS total_assets`

```
SELECT account_name ,sum(total_balance) from transaction 
where account_name IN('cash','a/r','supplies','prepaid','land','gold')
ORDER BY account_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `as total_assets` into the `select` clause.  This is used to define a column alias:

```
select account_name, sum(total_balance) as total_assets
from transaction 
where account_name in ('cash', 'a/r', 'supplies', 'prepaid', 'land', 'gold')
order by account_name;
```